# iOS7/iphone 5s home button tap API

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

So with this new fingerprint thing you only need to tap the home button and hold your finger for a few moments to unlock your phone. I was wondering if there's an API that lets us make use of the "Tap" functionality.

i.e. Let's say in my app, when the user taps the home button, my app does xyz.

Also, would it be possible for my app to read these taps when the screen is locked?

NOTE: By tap I do not mean pressing the button, just a tap, like when we unlock the iPhone 5s with the fingerprint scan.

I'm completely new to iOS development. So referencing libraries with links etc and basic tutorials might make things a bit clearer for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. This API does not exist. File a feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com. I can't imagine that this will get implemented though, given the possibility of abuse.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make an app which substitutes the lock/unlock button at the top of the iPhone. It's really annoying to actually having to press either the home button or the button at the top to bring on the lock screen to proceed to unlock the phone. They're really stiff. A tap would be more convenient. Any ideas?

Comment: Won't be possible, you should start looking for other ideas. Maybe it is possible with a jailbreak. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no public API for the Touch ID sensor... yet. And there may never be one.